# How to query multiple objects in apex batch

Tags: apex, batch

I want to retrieve `Leads` and `Accounts` in Apex `start` function and update the owner field
How can that be achieved?

```
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        //query leads and accounts
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> object) {
           //update leads and accounts
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
```

**Edit**

I have a custom object that has a field that contains a user Id.
If this field is updated from **user A Id** to **user B Id** for example, a trigger calls the batch method. Leads and Accounts where the owner is A need to be retrieved and then the owner field should be updated by the new value which is user Id B.

Comment: It can't be done with `QueryLocator`. You could do it by returning `List<SObject> start` instead, but that would be more limited in volume. Curious to know a little bit more about your requirements. Recommended approach could vary based on the scenario. What conditions lead records into this batch in the first place?

Comment: Just edited the post to clarify the scenario.

Comment: two batch jobs - one for leads, one for accounts

Answer (score 1):

You should never execute batches from a trigger context. It is highly likely that doing so will lead to many avoidable headaches. Optimal design pattern here would be to add a change tracking object you can batch over. Whenever your trigger detects this change, insert a record into the tracking table. Make sure it contains lookups `Old User` and `New User`, as well as a checkbox `Is Processed`. Your batch would simply pick up any records where the checkbox is false, find and update relevant records, then set the checkbox to true.